# Doing the requested change instead of the owner of the pull request

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I'm looking at a pull-request on GitHub, reviewers requested changes but the owner of the pull-request haven't done anything, most probably he doesn't know how to do. I'm curious about a way that is kind and doesn't hurt pull-request owner's contribution to complete his work.

- Instead of opening a new pull-request to the main repository, should I open a pull-request to his branch on his fork or which parts of my approach, should be changed?
- The main repository isn't mine, if it would be mine, what'd be different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the solution after forking the repository from `rookie_fork:pr_branch` and doing the changes, so, my approach was right and if it would be my repository:

- I'd just create another branch on my repository, and merge changes from `rookie_fork:pr_branch` to my `my_repo:new_branch`. And open a new pull request to `rookie_fork:pr_branch` from my `my_repo:new_branch`.

Then I'd question myself, *"Are all these efforts for not creating a new pr?"* And the answer is *"Yes, this is a more kind way".* At the end of the day, the main repository will have commits from him and me. And thanks to the [Tumbleweed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcBPL.gif) badge notification, I saw that no one answered this question.